# How to use next_posts_link/previous_posts_link for custom post types paginate?

Tags: custom-post-types, previous-post-link

I have a question about usage of previous_posts_link/next_posts_link. Is it possible to use it for custom post types too?

I like to hear from you.

Thanks in advance.
Casper

Comment: Try it. What are your results?

Comment: @toscho Notting is happening...

Comment: Are you referring to CPT archive page pagination or single CPT entries (next and previous single posts)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked for me. I have a custom post type called "feature" defined like this:

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'feature',
    'description'         => 'Product feature pages',
    'labels'              => array(
        'name'                => 'Features',
        'singular_name'       => 'Feature',
        'menu_name'           => 'Feature',
        'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Feature:',
        'all_items'           => 'All Features',
        'view_item'           => 'View Feature',
        'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Feature',
        'add_new'             => 'New Feature',
        'edit_item'           => 'Edit Feature',
        'update_item'         => 'Update Feature',
        'search_items'        => 'Search Feature',
        'not_found'           => 'No Features found',
        'not_found_in_trash'  => 'No Features found in Trash',
    ),
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'feature',
);
register_post_type( 'feature', $args );
```

Then I create a file called `single-feature.php` in my theme folder, and inside that file I have:

```
<ul class="pager">
              <li class="previous">
                  <?php 
                  previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous feature', 'mistcrm' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?>
              </li>
              <li class="next">
                <?php 
                  next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next feature', 'mistcrm' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Or if you didn't want to create a single-cpt.php file, you could simply hook in the links after the loop using the correct WordPress or theme specific hook and the conditional tag for your CPT.

Comment: In single-feature.php you only have the code you provided? (pager) no footer and other code to query your features ?

Answer (score 1):

They do work.

Just make sure you include both of them **INSIDE** the loop. Otherwise it will never know what is previous/next.

Answer (score 0):

I had used a plugin to create the custom post types and then found that none of the core functions would give me next / previous links to single custom posts.

I ended up writing a plugin that "seems" to work for me.

https://github.com/adampatterson/nextpost

Let me know if you have success of fail, it should give you next / previous links inside a single custom post, I don't think It will work in custom taxonomy but let me know :)